# Finding volume of a hyperboloid

Tags: calculus, volume

Given the hyperboloids

$$H_1 := \left\{ (x,y,z) : \frac{x^2}{500} + \frac{y^2}{500} - \frac{z^2}{2000} = 1 \right\}$$

and

$$H_2 := \left\{ (x,y,z) : \frac{x^2}{415} + \frac{y^2}{415}- \frac{z^2}{2000} = 1 \right\}$$

I want to find the volume of a "tower" between the two hyperboloids, i.e., inside $H_1$ and outside $H_2$. The given bounds for both equations is: $-65 \le z \le 15.$

Should I turn the equation into cylindrical coordinates? If so, how? and which equation can I integrate?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes, cylindrical, outer variable $z.$ For each $z$ value, $x^2 + y^2$ is bounded between $415 \left( 1 + \frac{z^2}{2000} \right)$ and $500 \left( 1 + \frac{z^2}{2000} \right).$ This should tell you how to find the bounds for $r.$ For a volume, you are just integrating $1$